# OpenGL - glBindTexture - premature optimisation?

Tags: optimization, opengl, binding, textures

I've seen sample code (most notably in iOS GL projects) where the current GL texture name is cached, and a comparison done before calling glBindTexture.  The goal is to avoid unnecessary calls to glBindTexture.

e.g.

```
if (textureName != cachedTextureName) {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureName);
    cachedTextureName = textureName;
}
```

This approach requires that ALL calls to glBindTexture be handled similarly, preferably through a wrapper.  But the inclusion of third-party code makes this problematic, as well as being *Yet Another Thing to Remember*.

**Q.** Is this a useful optimisation?  Or is the OpenGL implementation smart enough to disregard calls to glBlindTexture where the texture name has not changed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't called out in the spec as far as I've seen.  In practice is appears many implementations actually do some processing if you rebind the same texture as you'll see a relative performance drop if you don't test the current texture. I'd recommend using the test if possible just to ensure that implementation details don't have an adverse effect on your program.

Generally speaking it is quite useful to abstract over the OpenGL state machine with your own state handling so you can query state such as the bound texture or the active matrices without calling `glGet` which will almost always be slower than your custom handling.  This also allows you to prohibit invalid behavior and generally makes your program easier to reason about.

Comment: Thanks Ron. My natural inclination is to wrap it, but then there's the issue of third party code calling glBindTexture without using my cached state.

Comment: The ideal situation would be wrapping your code in a library that links to OpenGL and assume that the callers of your library won't deliberately grab your context and call OpenGL functions on it.  Alas, this isn't always feasible so you have to live with the OpenGL state machine and its foibles.